# How to get approximate result's rows count of the SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get very quick estimate of count of the rows of the result of heavy sql query. 
I'm not able to just look into index statistics, because of my query is based on multiply tables.

I guess, it could be some way to get estimated number of rows from execution plan builder. It's almost the same what I need.

Comment: I don't there is any way to accomplish what you are asking short of running the query with a count(*).

Comment: If you have a really complicated query you are just as well picking a number out of the air as looking at the execution plan.

Comment: What do you plan to do with this information anyway?

Comment: I need this information to decide to run on not the query itself _in my app_. So, looking into a plan itself is not an option.

Comment: So, information about query estimated execution time is suit as well.

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO a lot of people think they have complicated queries, when they really don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is to execute the query on a connection with `SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON;`. This will return the estimated plan XML but not actually execute the query. The `StatementEstRows` attribute of element `/StatementEstRows/BatchSequence/Batch/Statements/StmtSimple` will contain the row count estimate SQL Server uses for plan generation.

Note that `SET SHOWPLAN_XML` must be the only statement in the batch and the setting will remain on until `SET SHOWPLAN_XML OFF;` is executed or the connection closed.